# does anyone know a good mapinfo forum?

Tags: gis, forums, mapinfo

I'm new using mapinfo and I am going to work a lot with it. I haven't been able to find a good forum, making it impossible to get community driven assistance. I wish any of you could tell me if there is a good place to find mapinfo related help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MapInfo-L](http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l) has been the essential MapInfo forum for years. Originally it was an email list, but now it's on Google Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) doesn't have many MapInfo users... yet?